# Number of reference exist in another tables - PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, psql

I have more than 100 tables. User table is one among them. User related with multiple table. If i'm going to delete an user, i need to check any user table reference exist in other tables. So i need to get the number of foreign relation exists in other table. User additional will be stored in another table. So number of reference is more than 1, then i should not delete.

I'm working in PostgreSQL. I think it's possible in mysql. I dont know about Postgresql as i'm new to PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

When you define your foreign key you can give it the option to restrict the delete if any other table still holds a key. Here is the example from the [postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/ddl-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE order_items (
    product_no integer REFERENCES products ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    order_id integer REFERENCES orders ON DELETE CASCADE,
    quantity integer,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_no, order_id)
);
```

Comment: If reference exists, then it shouldn't be deleted. So i need to delete only the records that doesn't have any reference.

Comment: Yes, ON DELETE RESTRICT will prevent the row from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Place each delete in `begin exception` block inside loop and use error condition - `restrict_violation`:

```
    ...
    loop
        begin
            delete ... where id = 1;
        exception
            when restrict_violation then null
        end;
    end loop;
```

This way a user with a foreign relation will not be deleted and others without will.